# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes while using two sample independent t test

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I am trying to perform two sample t test. My data set consists of 744 rows and 186 columns for which I have calculated total sum and mean. I need to perform two sample t test. My csv looks like this from which I have to calculate ttest and rank sum test for each row as individual row denotes separate ID and have the corresponding values :

```
SRA ID  ERR169499            ERR169498           ERR169497
Label   1                    0                   1
TaxID   PRJEB3251_ERR169499  PRJEB3251_ERR169499 PRJEB3251_ERR169499
333046  0.05                 0.99                99.61
1049    0.03                 2.34                34.33
337090  0.01                 9.78                23.22
```

The labels 0 and 1 are for case and control respectively. So far I have done this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
from scipy.stats import ranksums

def transposer(filename):
file = open(filename, 'rt')
pd.read_csv(file).T.to_csv(str(filename).split("/")
[-1].split(".")[0]+'_transposed.csv',header=False)


pd.read_csv('project.csv').T.to_csv('transposed.csv', header=False)

file = open('transposed.csv', 'rt')
out = open('final_out.csv', 'w')
meta = open('Meta3251.csv', 'rt')
contents = {}
for ids in meta:
    contents[ids.split(',')[1]]=ids.split(',')[-1]
count = 0
for row in file:
    if count == 0:
    out.write('SraID, Label,'+row)
    count=1
else:

    try:
        pid = row.split(',')[0].split('_')[1]
out.write(pid.replace('\n','')+','+contents[pid].replace('\n','')
+','+str(row))
        out.flush()
    except:
        print(pid)
        pass
file.close()
out.close()
transposer('final_out.csv')
file1 = open('final_out_transposed.csv','rt')
label = []
data = {}

x = open('final_out_transposed.csv','rt')
for r in x:
    datas = r.split(',')
    if datas[0] == ' Label':
        label.append(r.split(",")[1:])
label = label[0]
label[-1] = label[-1].replace('\n','')
counter = len(label)
for row in file1:
    content = row.split(',')
if content[0]=='SraID' or content[0]== 'TaxID' or content[0]==' Label':
    pass
else:
    dt = row.split(',')
    dt[-1] = dt[-1].replace('\n','')

    data[dt[0]]=dt[1:]
keys = list(data)
sum_file = open('sum.csv','w')
sum_file.write('TaxId,sum_case,sum_ctrl,case_count,
ctrl_count,case_mean,ctrl_mean,\n')
for key in keys:
    sum_case = 0
    sum_ctrl = 0
    count_case = 0
    count_ctrl = 0
    mean_case = 0
    mean_ctrl = 0
for i in range(counter):
    if label[i] == '0':
        sum_case=np.float64(sum_case)+np.float64(data[key][i])
        count_case = count_case+1
        mean_case = sum_case/count_case
    else:
        sum_ctrl = np.float64(sum_ctrl)+np.float64(data[key][i])
        count_ctrl = count_ctrl+1
        mean_ctrl = sum_ctrl/count_ctrl
sum_file.write(key+','+str(np.float64((sum_case)))+','

+str(np.float64((sum_ctrl)))+','+str(np.float64((count_case)))        
+','+str(np.float64((count_ctrl)))+','+str(np.float64((mean_case)))
+','+str(np.float64((mean_ctrl)))+'\n')
sum_file.flush()
sum_file.close()

df  = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv', header=[1,2], index_col=[0])
case = df.xs('0', axis=1, level=0).dropna()
ctrl = df.xs('1', axis=1, level=0).dropna()
(tt_val, p_ttest) = ttest_ind(case, ctrl, equal_var=False)
print (tt_val)
print (p_ttest)
```

I am getting the error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (92,) (95,)

How can I handle this error. I cannot change my data.

Comment: would you say the error is for which line?

Comment: It is in the line `(tt_val, p_ttest) = ttest_ind(case, ctrl)`

Comment: When you drop rows based on na's and assign it two variables, they might not be of same length. What you need to do `inplace` the `dropna`'s and then take `ctrl` from there.

Comment: @KiriteeGak eveen with doing that im still having the error. The columns for case and control are actually 92 and 95.

Comment: @Media  any help on how to numpy broadcast will solve this I guess

Comment: @KiriteeGak any help on how to numpy broadcast will solve this I guess

Comment: At least point us to the line in which you are encountering the error. Debugging will be easier. And I am still quite sure what I had mentioned in my previous comment is the issue.

Comment: @KiriteeGak  Its in the line `(tt_val, p_ttest) = ttest_ind(case, ctrl, equal_var=False)`. I have calculated the frequency of case, control in my progarm as you can see and I have the number 92 as case i.e. label is 0, 95 as control i.e. label is 1

Comment: Try to do this `df_no_na=df.dropna(); (case, ctrl) = (df_no_na['a'], df_no_na['b'])` and do the `t_val, p_val = ...` step and tell me what error  comes up, if any.

Comment: @KiriteeGak Hi I got what the issue is. its actually the objects created by the `xs` method of the Pandas DataFrame look like two-dimensional arrays. These must be flattened to look like one-dimensional arrays when passed to `ttest_ind`. The values attribute of the Pandas objects gives a numpy array, and the `ravel()` method flattens the array to one-dimension. it should be `(tt_val,p_ttest ) = ttest_ind(case.values.ravel(), ctrl.values.ravel(), equal_var=False)` . With this its working fine.

Comment: Cool. :) Please provide the solution to your own question and mark the answer right, so that question wont pop again onto the homepage later.

Comment: @KiriteeGak Sure.. posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question would be :
The objects created by the `xs` method of the `Pandas DataFrame` look like `two-dimensional arrays`. These must be `flattened` to look like `one-dimensional arrays` when passed to `ttest_ind`. The values attribute of the Pandas objects gives a `numpy array`, and the `ravel()` method flattens the array to one-dimension. 
It would go like :

```
df  = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv', header=[1,2], index_col=[0])
case = df.xs('0', axis=1, level=0).dropna()
ctrl = df.xs('1', axis=1, level=0).dropna()
(tt_val,p_ttest ) = ttest_ind(case.values.ravel(), ctrl.values.ravel(), 
equal_var=False)
print (tt_val)
print(p_ttest)
```

Comment: Congrats for your effort